# Find the maximum of $(x_1\cdots x_n)^2$ subject to $x_1^2+\ldots +x_n^2=1$

Tags: analysis, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier, extremal-combinatorics

Find the maximum of $(x_1\cdots x_n)^2$ subject to $x_1^2+\ldots +x_n^2=1$ und show that $$\left (\prod_{k=1}^na_k\right )^{\frac{1}{n}}\leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^na_k$$

For the first part I applied the method of Lagrange multipliers.

We have the function $f(x_1, \ldots , x_n)=(x_1\cdot \ldots \cdot x_n)^2$ and the constraint $g(x,y,z)=x_1^2+ \ldots + x_n^2-1=0$.

The Lagrange function is \begin{equation*}L(x_1, \ldots , x_n  ,\lambda )=f(x_1, \ldots , x_n)+\lambda g(x_1, \ldots , x_n)=(x_1\cdot \ldots \cdot x_n)^2+\lambda \left (x_1^2+ \ldots + x_n^2-1\right )=\left (\prod_{j=1}^nx_j\right )^2+\lambda \left (\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^2-1\right )\end{equation*}
We calculate the partial derivatives of $L$ :
\begin{align*}&\frac{\partial}{\partial{x_i}}(x_1, \ldots , x_n  ,\lambda )=2\left (\prod_{j=1}^nx_j\right )\cdot \left (\prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^nx_j\right ) +2\lambda x_i  \\ & \frac{\partial}{\partial{\lambda }}L(x_1, \ldots , x_n  ,\lambda )=\sum_{j=1}^nx_j^2-1 \end{align*} with $1\leq i\leq n$.

To get the extrema we set the partial derivatives equal to zero.

Then we get the following system:
\begin{align*}&2\left (\prod_{j=1}^nx_j\right )\cdot \left (\prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^nx_j\right ) +2\lambda x_i =0 \Rightarrow x_i\cdot \prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^nx_j^2 +\lambda x_i =0 \Rightarrow x_i\cdot \left (\prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^nx_j^2 +\lambda \right ) =0 \\ & \sum_{j=1}^nx_j^2-1=0  \end{align*}

How can we continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, $x_i \ne 0$. Multiply each of your first $n$ equations by $x_i$ and add them up:
$$
 n\prod_{j=1}^nx_j^2+\lambda\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2 = 0,  
$$
$$
 n\prod_{j=1}^nx_j^2+\lambda= 0.  
$$
It follows that
$$
\lambda = -n\prod_{j=1}^nx_j^2, \quad \quad x_i = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.
$$

Comment: Why can we say that $x_i\neq 0$ ? Because $i$ is an arbitrary index and if for one $i$ we had $x_i=0$ then we would have that $x_i=0$ for all $i$ which cannot be true?

Comment: @MaryStar Hey Mary - what Zeekless is saying is that any such maximal instance surely has every $x_i$ non-zero, because if some $x_i$ were zero then the product would be zero, which surely isn't maximal.

Comment: Ah ok! To get the value of $x_i$ we replace $\lambda$ in $\displaystyle{x_i\cdot \left (\prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^nx_j^2 +\lambda \right ) =0 \Rightarrow \prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^nx_j^2 +\lambda =0}$ and get: 
\begin{align*}\prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^nx_j^2 -n \cdot \prod_{j=1}^nx_j^2 =0 &\Rightarrow \prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^nx_j^2 -n \cdot x_i^2 \cdot \prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^nx_j^2 =0\\ & \Rightarrow \prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^nx_j^2 \left (1-n \cdot x_i^2 \right ) =0\\ & \overset{x_i\neq 0}{ \Rightarrow }1-n \cdot x_i^2=0\\ & \Rightarrow x_i^2=\frac{1}{n}  \\ & \Rightarrow x_i=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\end{align*} right?

Comment: So since $i$ is an arbitrary index we get $x_1=x_2=\ldots =x_n=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, right? Or do we consider only the positiv one?

Comment: @MaryStar Your derivations are correct, and yes: both positive and negative $x_i$ will do, since both the objective function and the constraints depend on $x_i^2$, not on $x_i$ itself.

Comment: Great, so we get that the extrema is at $\left (\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}, \ldots , \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right )$ and it is equal to $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{n^n}}$. Do we have to show also that it is a maximum?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, we have to. If $x_1\cdot \dots x_n$ is greater than $\frac{1}{n^n}$, then at least one $x_i$ is greater than $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. But no such point is a solution to your system of equations. Finally: your system of equations captures the global maximum since the set defined by $x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2 = 1$ is compact.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much!! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Just to provide a non-calculus alternative.

We can show that the maximum of $(x_1x_2\cdots x_n)^2$ subject to $x_1^2 + \cdots +x_n^2 =1$ must occur when $x_1^2 = \cdots = x_n^2$ by using AM-GM for two non-negatives (which is relatively easy to show):

**AM-GM for two non-neagives:** If $A,B\ge 0$, then $(A+B)/2 \ge \sqrt{AB}$ and equality holds if and only if $A=B$. (Proof of this later, or try it yourself.)

Now we prove that this maximum occurs when $x_1^2 =\cdots = x_n^2$. Suppose to the contrary, say $x_1^2\neq x_2^2$. Denote the maximum value as $M$ where $$M = (x_1^2 x_2^2)(x_3\cdots x_n)^2.$$
Now $x_1^2 + x_2 ^2 +\cdots+ x_n^2 = 1$, so $x_1^2 + x_2 ^2 = 1-Q$ for some $Q$. I claim we can pick better values for $x_1$ and $x_2$ that improves the maximum. Indeed, set $y_1 = y_2 = \sqrt{\frac{1-Q}{2}}$. Then note $y_1 ^2 + y_2 ^2 = 1-Q$, so $$y_1^2 +y_2 ^2 + x_3 ^2 +\cdots + x_n^2 = 1.$$ And by AM-GM for two non-negatives, we have $$x_1^2x_2^2 < \left(\frac{x_1^2+x_2^2}{2}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{1-Q}{2}\right)^2 = y_1^2y_2^2,$$ and note this inequality is **strict** as $x_1^2\neq x_2^2$.

Hence $y_1^2y_2^2(x_3\cdots x_n)^2> M$, contradicting the maximality of $M$.

Thus we conclude $x_i^2$ are all the same values when achieving maximum and hence $x_i^2 = 1/n$.  $\blacksquare$

---

**Proof of AM-GM for two non-negatives.**

The inequality is straightforward as $0\le (\sqrt A - \sqrt B)^2 = A + B -2\sqrt{AB} $, so $ \sqrt{AB}\le (A+B)/2$. For the equality case, note $ \sqrt{AB} =  (A+B)/2$ if and only if $(\sqrt A - \sqrt B)^2 = 0 $, if and only if $A=B$. $\blacksquare$

---

Remark. Of course we will have to believe that $(x_1x_2\cdots x_n)^2$ *will* attain a maximum somewhere on the unit sphere to begin with, which is true as $f(x_i)=(x_1\cdots x_n)^2$ is continuous on the compact unit sphere (extreme value theorem). This will be trickier to justify, a non-analysis proof eludes me at the moment.

Remark 2. It isn't too surprising we involve AM-GM here, as you may observe that the corollary of this problem is to demonstrate the general AM-GM inequality for $n$ non-negatives.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Lagrange multipliers are just asking (when gradients of both constraint and objective functions are nonzero) where they are parallel. This is simply, in the case that all partials are nonzero, asking for points where the ratios of the partials all come out the same.

If any element is zero, the product is zero. Otherwise, we can demand all $x_i > 0$ and continue. The $x_i$ partial of $P^2$ is $$2 \frac{P^2}{x_i}$$
where $P$ is the product of the $x_i$

The $x_i$ partial of the sum of squares is $$ 2 x_i$$

Each ratio is $$ \frac{P^2}{x_i^2}$$  Lagrange multipliers demand all these ratios equal, meaning all the $x_i^2$ must be equal. So, each $$ x_i = \frac{1}{\sqrt n} $$

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I thought worth mentioning it.

Set $y_k = x_k^2$ for $k=1\ldots n$. So, to maximize is

$$\prod_{k=1}^n y_k \text{  subject to  } \sum_{k=1}^ny_k =1\text{  with  } y_1,\ldots ,y_n \geq 0$$

Since the product is $0$ if any of the $y_k$ is zero, we can assume $y_1,\ldots ,y_n > 0$.

Now, Jensen (or concavity of $\ln$) gives immediately

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \ln y_k \leq n \ln \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{y_k}n = \ln \frac 1{n^n}$$

Hence,

$$\prod_{k=1}^n x_k^2 = \prod_{k=1}^n y_k \leq \frac 1{n^n}$$

and equality is reached for $y_k = \frac 1n \Leftrightarrow x_k =\pm \frac 1{\sqrt n}$.